# Any better way of assigning String value, eliminating multiple If Else blocks in Java

Tags: java

I wanted to assign a String constant based on other string value which is sent as a parameter from the other program. like shown below
test is the String variable sent from Main program, in this helper method I need to compare and assign some other string value and send the result back to Main Program

For example :

```
public String assignString(String test){ 
String returnString = new String();
if(test.startsWith("hi"))
  returnString  = "Condition 1";
else if(test.startsWith("hello"))
  returnString  = "Hello Welcome";
else if(test.startsWith("Sunday"))
  returnString  = "Today is Sunday";
else if(test.startsWith("monday"))
  returnString  = "today is Monday";
else{
returnString  = "today is good day";
}

return returnString;
}
```

Above way is one way of doing.
Other would be using Switch statement
But I am trying to find any other alternative and better way of implementing the same solution.

SOme how I am not satisfied with Lot of if Else statements and its cumbersome to maintain. In the above example I have used only 3, but in real time application its more than 15 checks I need to do.

Please suggest and Thanks in advance

Comment: You could iterate over a hashmap with the `startsWith` conditions and return the value, but other than that, not a lot. It's Java.

Comment: The initial problem is that your check your input using ``startsWith``. You could create a map and use substring to map the first N characters to an output value.

Comment: For all the `returnString` which starts with "Today is", just add the parameter of `startsWith()` to a constant string "Today is"  and you got a generic solution for many cases.

Comment: instead of Starts with I can use equalIgnoreCase as well.

Answer (score 2):

Dave Newton suggestion is good.

A alternative and close way would be to introduce a class with two methods :

- `boolean matches(String test)`
- `String getValue()`

This way avoids the infernal switch case but allows also to isolate the logic rule. In this way you can unit test it easily and also reuse the class for similar processing as it has a broad contract matcher.
If it makes sense, you could even introduce a `Rule` interface.

```
public class RuleImpl { 

    private String startPattern;
    private String value;

    public RuleImpl(String startPattern, String value){
       this.startPattern = startPattern;
       this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean matches(String test){ 
       if(test.startsWith(startPattern)){
           return true;
       }
         return false;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

You can write now :

```
List<RuleImpl> rules = Arrays.asList(
                       new RuleImpl("monday", "today is Monday"),
                       new RuleImpl("hello",  "Hello Welcome"),
                       new RuleImpl("Sunday", "Today is Sunday")
                       );
```

And the processing could be now :

```
String test = "string to test";

for (RuleImpl rule : rules){       
   if (rule.matches(test)){
      return rule.getValue();
   }
 } 
 return null;
```

Comment: I was going to suggest a bit-wise comparison, merging conditions in bits. However, this solution is a lot cleaner

Comment: @older coder  thanks a lot. This solution  requires one additional class but it it is rather cheap.

Answer (score 1):

The same logic as if-else but with a properly formated nested ternary operators could look like :

```
public static String assignString(String test){         
    return   test.startsWith("hi")      ?"Condition 1"
            :test.startsWith("hello")   ?"Hello Welcome"
            :test.startsWith("Sunday")  ?"Today is Sunday"
            :test.startsWith("monday")  ?"today is Monday"
            :"today is good day";        
}
```

Comment: Do you thing performance wise it would help me with above way?

Comment: I do not think that there's any performance difference. And if there is a difference it will be negligible. But writing your code this way will make it shorter and more readable. I prefer where ever applicable a shorter code that focuses on the relevant part than  trivial performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away with not using `String.startsWith`, you might try something like this:

```
private static final Map<String, String> greetings = new HashMap<>();

static {
    greetings.put("hi", "Condition 1");
    greetings.put("hello", "Hello Welcome");
    greetings.put("sunday", "Today is Sunday");
    greetings.put("monday", "today is Monday");
}

public String assignString(String test) {
    return greetings.getOrDefault(test.toLowerCase(), "today is good day");
}
```